# Plotting the Mandelbrot set at different zoom levels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fractals

I'm interested in making an animated movie of a zoom in on a part of the Mandelbrot set.  My code works well for a few zooms, but upon trying to zoom in quite far, I find that the fractal becomes "smoothed out".  Am I missing something that prevents me from seeing the fractal structure at higher zoom levels?  Am I hitting machine precision in the computations?  Here's what I'm talking about:

Zoom level 3:
[image: zoom level 3]
Zoom level 9:
[image: zoom level 9]
Zoom level 20:
[image: zoom level 20]

The first plot looks good, the second is okay, and the third is not fractal at all.

If there are any other deficiencies or improvements I'd be glad to hear about them as well.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import animation
import time

# some interesting places in the set
# http://www.nahee.com/Derbyshire/manguide.html

N = 500
nIts = 25
nZooms = 50
x0=0
y0=-1

movie = np.zeros([N,N,nZooms])

x = np.linspace(-2,1,N)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
c = X + 1j*Y
z = 0*c
for i in range(nIts):
    z = z**2 + c

mask = np.abs(z) < 1
z[z>1]=0
z[np.isnan(z)]=0
movie[:,:,0] = mask


# plotting stuff
for j in range(1,nZooms):
    h=1./(2**j)
    print "Plot number ", j
    x = x0+h*np.linspace(-1,1,N)
    y = y0+h*np.linspace(-1,1,N)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    c = X + 1j*Y
    z = 0*c
    for i in range(nIts):
        z = z**2 + c

    mask = np.abs(z) < 1
    z[z>1]=0
    z[np.isnan(z)]=0
    movie[:,:,j] = mask

fig = plt.figure()

for j in range(nZooms):
    name = "image%d.png" % j
    plt.imshow(movie[:,:,j], cmap = 'RdBu')
    plt.gray()
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.axis('off')
    # plt.show()
    fig.savefig(name)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Are you seeking a general review to improve any and all aspects of your code, or just to address that specific concern?

Comment: @Phrancis If there are any other deficiencies, I'd be glad to hear about them.

Comment: Ok I made an edit to mention that. Hope you get some great answers!

Comment: Never seen code that uses x and X. Would vote seriously against doing that.

Comment: Are you sure the numeric type you're using has enough precision for the zoom level you want? If not, that seems like a reasonable reason for it not being fractal at all.

Comment: Try a higher iteration count for deeper zooms. At zoom X20, go with at least 100 iterations. Low iteration counts lead to low detail.

Comment: Also, you repeat the iteration code twice, once before and once after `#plotting stuff`. If that is intentional, it is redundant? Explain why you need to repeat the code. Can't it be extracted into a function (hint: it can).

Comment: In fact, scale the maximum iteration count linearly with the zoom depth. That should help.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I tried both, with only moderate improvement in resolution.  It still rounds out on higher zoom levels.  With more iterations you can't see anything, the whole image becomes blacked out by the mask.  I also switched to 128 bit accuracy in numpy.

Comment: That's supposed to happen. Detail increases with higher iteration counts, so there's less white to see in the image. Now, try using higher resolution - much higher - at least 640x480. Recommended 1920x1080, but Python might a bit too slow for that ;)

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Thank you for all the help.  I'll give it a shot and see if I can get some higher resolution.  At this point I'm not too concerned with the speed, I just really want some nice pictures!